# ASP.NET Javascript and postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

I have a page located in an `iframe` of another page. It calls a `js` function like this:

```
function F(a)  
{  
    parent.document.getElementById('A').value = a;
    parent.document.getElementById('B').click();
}
```

It results in page reloading. How can I prevent it? Previously I've used `return false;` and it worked. But not in this case.

Answer (score 1):

F("some value"); return false;
after calling the function not inside.

Comment: Function is called when link clicked. `<a href="javascript:F('qwerty');>Link</a>`. So if I add `return false;` here it will not work.

Comment: <a href="javascript:F('qwerty'); return false;">Link</a>

Comment: Nothing happens when I click it.

Comment: are you handling the onclick of your botton? in my replicated example I have this: <input type="button" id="B" onclick="foo();" /> So when I call F function the click of B input call the foo function.

Comment: I'm using asp.net button `<asp:Button ID="B" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="B_Click" />`

Comment: and you have your code in server side right? like public void B_Click(object sender, EventArgs args) -- if that it's true, you'll need an ajax call to that code, in asp.net you can achieve this by creating an asp.net ajax client side service or an wcf ajax service, you can call the B server side method in javascript as an service function. Any ASP.NET book in the ajax section talk about it, the Apress book of Matthew MacDonald does it.

Comment: The solution is not as easy as I thought :) I'll try it. Thx.